# React native create a custom folder and save photos using react-native-crop-picker android

Tags: react-native, gallery, photo, picker, react-native-image-crop-picker

I'm using `react-native-image-crop-picker`. I want to save the photos to the gallery or to a custom folder taken from the camera using `react-native-image-crop-picker`. Normally the photos taken from the `react-native-image-crop-picker` are saved in the cache folder. I want to change it to a custom folder and display the images in the gallery with an auto-generated name like the *first photo - p1.jpg, second photo - p2.jpg,* Is there any way to implement it.

```
const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
        ImagePicker.openCamera({
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            cropping: true,
            includeBase64: true,
            freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
            compressImageQuality: 0,
            enableRotationGesture: true,
          }).then(image => {
            console.log(image);
          });
          
        console.warn('Take photo');
     }
```

[react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) this is what i used

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using [rn-fetch-blob - writeFile method](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#writefilepathstring-contentstring--array-encodingstringpromise)

Below is a sample functons to achieve above combining both `react-native-image-crop-picker` and `rn-fetch-blob`

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

const imageCropper = () => {
  ImagePicker.openCamera({
    cropping: true,
    mediaType: 'photo',
    includeBase64: true,
  }).then((imageData) => {
    const base64Data = imageData.data;
    const fileName = getUniqueFileName('jpg');
    writeFileToStorage(base64Data, fileName);
  });
};

const getUniqueFileName = (fileExt) => {
  //It is better naming file with current timestamp to achieve unique name
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var date = d.getDate();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  var fileName = 'IMG' + year + month + date + hour + minute + '.' + fileExt;
  return fileName;
};

const writeFileToStorage = async (base64Data, fileName) => {
  try {
    const result = await PermissionsAndroid.request(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
      var folderPath = dirs.SDCardDir + '/Custom Folder/';
      var fullPath = folderPath + fileName;

      RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(folderPath).then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
      });

      RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(fullPath, base64Data, 'base64').then((res) => {
        console.log('file saved :', res);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Permission Not Granted');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: This code work for me, but you're doing a little bit mistake while creating the custom folder here:
```RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(folderPath).then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
      });```
Everytime we'll run this code it will create the folder again and again, to avoid this we first need to check if the folder is already exist or not:

```if (!(await RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(folderPath))) {
          RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(folderPath).then((res) => {
            console.log("Folder created:", res);
          });
        }```

Comment: If I remember correctly, when calling`RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir` with a directory path that already exists, it will not create the folder again and again, and it won't throw an error either. It will simply return a successful response indicating that the directory already exists.